# attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase error on first launch

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I am having a big problem with my database. When I try to make the first call to the database since the app launches, I get a crash saying:
`attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase /data/user/0/<path_to_db>`

I am using a DBHelper class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

When I launch the app the first time, it should create the DB etc, and then have an empty DB which should still allow me to do some queries on it.

However, when I do my first query, it crashes with the above error.
Here's the query:

```
public TerminalList getTerminalLocations() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(LOCATION_TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    //do stuff
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return locationList;
}
```

Its crashing on the first line!!
`SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();`

It doesn't even get as far as the cursor!
How is this possible? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Does it make a difference that this is being called from the `OnCreateView` of my fragment? Here is how I call it. Its pretty standard:

```
private void getLocations() {
    DBHelper db = DBHelper.getInstance(getActivity());
    TerminalList locations = db.getTerminalLocations();
    //do stuff
}
```

I've tried commenting out this call, but it pushes the problem to the next DB call, so is happening with every single DB call in the app!!

Thanks.

Comment: Try `DBHelper dbhelper = new DBHelper(this);` then `SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();`

Comment: The `getTerminalLocations` method is actually inside the `DBHelper` class. so its `dbHelper.getTerminalLocations()`

Comment: Okay, `getLocations()` currently resides in your fragment's `OnCreateView` & `getTerminalLocations()` resides in the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I would try `DBHelper dbhelper = DBHelper.getInstance(getActivity());` followed by `SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();` then your `db.query(...)` call. All under `getLocations()`, then if need be, you save the `cursor` contents to `TerminalList`.

Comment: Ye I was considering doing that, but then what is the purpose of using a `DBHelper`? I want to be able to just call a method in a class that handles all the DB calls. I always assumed that was the job of the DBHelper on top of the SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: SQLiteOpenHelper is just class that helps you create the SQLite database. You could implement a method that takes in the DB and builds a query from it if you want to abstract some of your DB operations.

Comment: Do you need help with that too?

Comment: Hi Daniel, no thanks. That's actually what I've already done. I've been playing with my code here and every method where I use `getReadableDatabase` I also use `db.close()`. I got rid of all those close statements and now it works. I'll have to revisit my code and maybe refactor to add another layer of abstraction around my DBHelper. Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops I didn't realize you responded. Well you can mark it as answered if you want. As far as closing the cursor & the db is concerned, the safest place to do so is on your activity's `onDestroy()`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this for the utility method:

```
public Cursor getWhatyouNeed(SQLiteDatabase db, params...) {
    Cursor yourData = db.query(your_query_params...);
    // your logic
    return yourData;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think the safest thing to do is create another layer of abstraction and pass a `db` to each method call. I'll go with that option. Cheers.